# How to set link(end_effector) pose?

Tags: ros, kinematics, moveit, ik, ur10

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm working with the ur10 model and I'm trying to get a way of controlling it by setting a pose for the end-effector. However I have no clue on how to do it. I tried the tutorial of movit regarding [kinematics](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/pr2_tutorials/kinematics/src/doc/kinematic_model_tutorial.html). But in the tutorial they calculate the IK from the value calculated from the DK for the end-effector but I want to set manually the values of the end-effector. So I tried to do the same way as they do for the joints:

```
kinematic_state->setRandomPosition(joint_model_group);
```

but had no success in finding a similar function for the links as there are for setting the joint values. Is there any other way I can do this, in order I can manually write the x,y,z values?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282153/how-to-set-link(end_effector)-pose?/) by [JuanTelo](https://answers.ros.org/users/32449/juantelo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2018-02-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the [setFromIK](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/moveit_core/html/classmoveit_1_1core_1_1RobotState.html#ab816880027ef7e63bbdef22a0497cc78) method

---

Originally posted by [jrgnicho](https://answers.ros.org/users/22410/jrgnicho/) with karma: 486 on 2018-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JuanTelo](https://answers.ros.org/users/32449/juantelo/) on 2018-02-08**:
@jrgnicho that seems the way to go but can you help me here, I defined the pose through `geometry_msgs::Pose end target;`

but now how can turn it into `const Eigen::Affine3d &   pose`, as required in the documentation?

**Comment by [jrgnicho](https://answers.ros.org/users/22410/jrgnicho/) on 2018-02-08**:
There are multiple flavors of that function, one of them takes a geometry_msgs::Pose type.  However if you need to convert between various types within a ROS program you can always use the this conversion utility [header](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/tf_conversions/html/c++/tf__eigen_8h.html)